# Считается ли слово "ни*уя" усиливающим отрицание?

Tags: частица-не, обсценная-лексика

Считается ли слово "ни*уя" усиливающим отрицание? Это важно, к примеру, в написании с частицей "не".

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая, что в данном контексте слово "ни*уя" является синонимом слова "ничего", то оно, безусловно, может усиливать отрицание. Соответственно, с частицей "не" это слово используется аналогично слову "ничего".
Примеры:

> Ничего не видно - *Ни*уя не видно*.
>   Ничего не нужно - *Ни*уя не нужно*.